# XUL button looks like disabled and is not "pushable" (but onclick function is invoked)

Tags: button, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox extension. I'm familiar with JS, CSS, XML but new to XUL.

I want to override Downloads in the way that adds a button next to each downloaded file to rename it. I've already done it (placing a button and handling rename logic).

The thing that left is UI. The button looks like disabled, but apparently is not, because I can click it and the popup appears.

Here it is how it looks now:

[image: XUL button in Firefox downloads]

and the corresponding code:

```
<xul:button label="Rename" tabindex="1" onclick="foo()"/>
```

Adding `disabled="false"` doesn't help. I can add `style="color:black; text-shadow:0 0;"` and *this makes it look like intended*, but there are several problems (and I guess disabled-like look might be the cause):

- The button I added is not "pushable" in the manner like the native "Clear list" button (pushing it doesn't change its look, i.e. it doesn't "go down"). However, `foo()` is invoked.
- I can't navigate to the button with <kbd>Tab</kbd> from keyboard.
- I've read one should prefer `command` / `oncommand` instead of `onclick` (because of <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigation for instance), but in my example, only `onclick` invokes `foo()`. The two other don't work.

In case more detailed code is needed (I borrowed it entirely from some other extension):

```xml
 <binding id="download-done" extends="chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/download.xml#download-base">
   <content>
     <xul:hbox flex="1">
       ...
       <xul:vbox pack="start" flex="1">
         ...
         <xul:hbox align="center" flex="1">
           <xul:label xbl:inherits="value=status,tooltiptext=statusTip" crop="end" flex="1" class="status"/>
           <xul:button label="Rename" tabindex="1" onclick="foo()"/>
         </xul:hbox>
       </xul:vbox>
     </xul:hbox>
   </content>  
 </binding>
```

Help greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1**

The code I presented above was taken from original Firefox [download.xml](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/mozilla-central/toolkit/mozapps/downloads/content/download.xml.html) (`<binding id="download-done">`) and changed only by adding my  `<xul:button>`.

For the things to be even more weird, I've taken, from the same file, two another bindings ( `<binding id="download-paused">` and `<binding id="download-downloading">`) and added exactly the same `<xul:button>` to them, and in both cases, the button is both "pushable" and black (in short, normal, as it should be). It is also navigable from keyboard with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, even without setting `tabindex` explicitly.

Comment: can you post your wip some place, like github? so that we can fiddle with it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest :) The problem still persist with Fx 12; I don't have much time right now to do it, I'll try in next few weeks to improve the code a bit and push it.

Comment: Did you check the default CSS files to identify which rules are causing the problem? CSS files will be chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/downloads.css and chrome://mozapps/skin/downloads/downloads.css as mentioned in chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/downloads.xul